# Which non-compact quaternion-Kähler spaces are Kähler?

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, symmetric-spaces

The list of quaternion-Kähler *compact* *symmetric* spaces can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion-K%C3%A4hler_symmetric_space). I am curious to know which of the *non-compact* versions of these spaces are Kähler. If the answer is known also for *non-symmetric non-compact* quaternion-Kähler spaces (of negative scalar curvature), it'd be great to know this too.

Any reference which explicitly addresses the issue would be appreciated.

(cross-posted to mathoverflow - [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398381/which-non-compact-quaternion-k%C3%A4hler-spaces-are-k%C3%A4hler))